# FaceBookSDK4.0.1 in android 5.0 cannot fetch friendList,cause by ERROR 400

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I make a app with FacebookSDK,and it can fetch friendList in android 4.4,but it didn't work in  android5.0.

```
public static boolean isLogin(){
        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null){
            Log.d("fb", "fb not login");
            return false;
        }else if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().isExpired()){
            Log.d("fb", "fb token expired");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I debug this ,and found the accessToke is right : {AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[public_profile, user_friends]}

```
    public static void makeInviteFriendsRequest(final String msg) {
        // Make an API call to get user data and define a
        // new callback to handle the response.
        SuspensionButton.getInstance().getGameActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("fb","fb makeInviteFriendsRequest run");
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONArrayCallback() {//Callback

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONArray result, GraphResponse response) {
                                SuspensionButton.getInstance().removeLoading();
                                InviteGen.fbJAarry=result;
                                SuspensionButton.getInstance().showBoardActivity("1","");
                            }
                        });
                request.executeAsync();
            }
        });
    }
```

Then I debug at "newMyFriendsRequest",and found it's the same accessToke,have same id and content.But the response is occur an error:**An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.**
Does anyone know what am I missed?
Apologize for my English,hope I explain well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake finally.I edit the sdk code's 'MY_FRIENDS' attribute,change to 'me/invitable_friends?limit=50', and I remove the code that behind '?',then android 5.0 can get friends's data . But I don't know why,maybe someone can tell me.